# Batch reading file info

Tags: batch-file

so i need to write a batch, that reads a .log file and does certain tasks with it.
1. Count the number of logins
2. Show ip address and file of successful login cases and at the end count how many of them took place  (error code 200)
3. Show ip address and file of unsuccessful login cases and at the end count how many of them took place (error code 404)

here is my program.

```
@echo off
:pasirinkimas
cls
echo Iveskite 1, jei norite pamatyti visu bandymu prisijungti skaiciu.
echo Iveskite 2, jei norite pamatyti informacija apie visus sekmingus prisijungimus.
echo Iveskite 3, jei norite pamatyti informacija apie visus nesekmingus prisijungimus.
echo Iveskite 4, jei norite baigti darba.

set /p pasirinkimas= Iveskite pasirinkima: 

if %pasirinkimas% == 1 goto bandymai
if %pasirinkimas% == 2 goto sekme
if %pasirinkimas% == 3 goto nesekme
if %pasirinkimas% == 4 goto pabaiga
goto pasirinkimas

:bandymai
echo Prisijungimu skaicius:
findstr "^[1-9]" apache.log | find /v "" /c 
pause>null
goto pasirinkimas

:sekme
findstr /c:" 200 " apache.log>null
for /f "tokens=1,7" %%G in (null) do echo %%G %%H
echo Sekmingu prisijungimu skaicius:
find /c " 200 " null 
pause>null
goto pasirinkimas

:nesekme
findstr /c:" 404 " apache.log>null
for /f "tokens=1,7" %%G in (null) do echo %%G %%H
echo Nesekmingu prisijungimu skaicius:
find /c " 404 " null  
goto pasirinkimas

pause>null

:pabaiga
exit
```

it works 100%. I just wanted to as if i could achieve the same result without redirecting **findstr** output to null file? or should i not worry about it?
here is my attempted version of the code without redirecting output to null file

```
:sekme
findstr " 200 " apache.log | find /v " " 
for /f "tokens=1,7" %%G in ('findstr " 200 " apache.log') do echo %%G %%H
```

with this the program DOES display the needed output on the screen but it takes about 8-10 seconds to do that (if file was bigger the time would grow i believe). plus i have no idea how to count the output lines. tried to do it on the same principle as in the first task **:bandymai** but failed miserably.
Can anyone help?

EDIT:
couple of log file lines

```
67.195.112.96 - - [22/Feb/2010:00:06:03 +0200] "GET /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=118 HTTP/1.0" 200 41119 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
67.195.112.96 - - [22/Feb/2010:00:06:04 +0200] "GET /www/css/master.css HTTP/1.0" 304 145 "http://jazz.lt/www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=118" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp/3.0; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
88.118.90.240 - - [22/Feb/2010:00:09:43 +0200] "GET /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30 HTTP/1.1" 200 13140 "http://www.google.lt/search?hl=lt&source=hp&q=gintaras+stankunas&btnG=Google+Paie%C5%A1ka&meta=&aq=f&oq=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.89 Safari/532.5"
88.118.90.240 - - [22/Feb/2010:00:09:43 +0200] "GET /www/javascript/swfobject.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8969 "http://www.jazz.lt/www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.89 Safari/532.5"
88.118.90.240 - - [22/Feb/2010:00:09:43 +0200] "GET /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30 HTTP/1.1" 200 40199 "http://www.google.lt/search?hl=lt&source=hp&q=gintaras+stankunas&btnG=Google+Paie%C5%A1ka&meta=&aq=f&oq=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.89 Safari/532.5"
```

Comment: sry for non-english names in the script, if needed i can change them (if they are getting in the way of understanding or smth)

Comment: `findstr " 200 "` does *not* search for `<space>200<space>`. To do so, use `findstr /c:" 200 "` or `findstr "\<200\>"` or `find " 200 "`

Comment: but it does. i know for a fact that there are 588 instances of 404. if i do findstr "404" i get 588 (because there are cases of 404 not only in error code place). if i use findstr " 404 " i get 544 :/ (though u are correct that this form was incorrect)

Comment: you read the file several times. That is time consuming, so you should avoid it. Can you edit your question to show a few representative lines of the logfile?

Comment: oops, my bad, i thought i did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert a counter into the loop to avoid reading the file twice:

```
:sekme
set count=0
for /f "tokens=1,7" %%G in ('type apache.log^|find " 200 "') do (
  echo %%G %%H
  set /a count+=1
)
echo Sekmingu prisijungimu skaicius: %count%
```

Comment: **type apache.log^|find " 200 "** why ^ after log?

Comment: btw, checked it, i try tu use 2 option again without starting batch over, every time i do this using this code the answer gets bigger by 7111. it doesnt set the **count** variable to 0 again

Comment: the `^` is to "escape" the pipe-symbol `|`, because else it would produce a Syntax error (due to the way, `for` works). Are you sure, you typed `set count=0` correctly (no space before the `=`)?

Comment: `/p` ? `/p` is for user input. You don't want user input with the counter.

Comment: yeah, u're right. but still, that doesnt change the fact that it takes like 4 seconds to do this operation

Answer (score 0):

Count all error codes returned (seems to be 9th token in your log file) as in next code snippet:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

rem  empty/delete all `_conn` environment variables in next loop
for /F "delims==" %%G in ('set _conn 2^>^NUL') do set "%%G="

for /f "tokens=1,7,9" %%G in (
  'findstr "^[1-9]" d:\test\apache.log'
) do (
  set /A "_connALL+=1"
  set /A "_conn%%I+=1"
  echo %%G %%I %%H
)
rem display counters in next line
set _conn
```

**Output** for slightly modified `apache.log` file (pasted twice and then changed some of 9th tokens):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\33133270.bat
67.195.112.96 200 /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=118
67.195.112.96 304 /www/css/master.css
88.118.90.240 200 /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30
88.118.90.240 404 /www/javascript/swfobject.js
88.118.90.240 200 /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30
67.195.112.96 404 /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=118
67.195.112.96 304 /www/css/master.css
88.118.90.240 200 /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30
88.118.90.240 404 /www/javascript/swfobject.js
88.118.90.240 200 /www/kurpiai/dalyviai/?did=30
_conn200=5
_conn304=2
_conn404=3
_connALL=10

==>
```